Treatment of a Chandala who has good Moral Character
If a Chandala had good moral character can one give him gifts and treat him more than what is stated in Dharmashastras. Please answer from Dharmasutras/sastras and Nitisastras.

One should respect Chandalas just like any others.

Disregarding the ridicule of one’s companions, one should give up the
bodily conception and its accompanying embarrassment. One should offer
obeisances before all — even the dogs, outcastes, cows and asses —
falling flat upon the ground like a rod.
[Bhagavata Purana 11.29.16]


Didn’t read my full question

@Haridasa I saw your question is about Dharmasastras, but dharmasastras alone aren't our scriptures.

I understand , but I wanted the answer to be from dharmashastras

Is this an authentic verse?

Gita 5-18 itself says - see same atman in brahmin, chandala, cow, elephant or dog.
Treatment should ideally follow from this. Good morale is not necessary condition.

Didn't listen to the second part.

Gita is regarded highly among Hindu shashtras. I thought that was obvious. In case of conflict, it is used as more important reference.

Please read the question
